# Possible to see on which regex is matched?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

Is it possible in C# to see on which Regex is matched?

So for example, if we have this Regex:

```
aaa[0-9]{2}\.zip|bbb[0-9]{2}\.zip
```

And we find `bbb10.zip` with the regex.

Is it then possible to see that the pattern that matched (it is `bbb[0-9]{2}.zip`)?

Comment: Thanks! However, my question is not entirely clear I see now. Is it also possible to get the regex itself, i.e. `bbb[0-9]{2}.zip`

Answer (score 1):

You may define a list of the patterns and build a pattern with alternatives wrapped in capturing groups. Then, once the match is found, you may loop through the groups and find the matched one.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var p = new[] {
            @"aaa[0-9]{2}\.zip",
            @"bbb[0-9]{2}\.zip"
        };
        var pat = new Regex($"({string.Join(")|(", p)})");
        var match = pat.Match("We have bbb12.zip match");
        for (var n=1; n <= p.Count(); n++)
        {
            if (match.Groups[n].Success) 
            {
                Console.Write("{0} group matched, the pattern is {1}", n, p[n-1]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/rKPo7F), output - `2 group matched, the pattern is bbb[0-9]{2}\.zip`.

The regex will look like `(aaa[0-9]{2}\.zip)|(bbb[0-9]{2}\.zip)` where you clearly see two capturing groups.

Note that capturing group IDs start with 1, since `match.Groups[0].Value` is equal to `match.Value`, the whole match, that is why `for` loop starts with `n=1`.

Comment: That's nifty with the dynamic groups and the alternations ++